# How to convert a Raw body data request for an API to ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postman

I am currently using postman to make an API request that pushes body data. I can get this to work either using "x-www-form-urlencoded" or "raw".  See examples below:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to convert this to an ajax javascript request but unsure on how to format the body/data text.  Here is my script:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token',
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
data: {

 " grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=***
&client_secret=***
&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api "



},
success: (data) => {
console.log(data.token)
},
error: (data) => {
console.log('rr', data)
}
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're explicitly sending it as JSON though, which you do not want. A very generic $.ajax call should work. Remove the `headers` part and use `data: { grant_type: "client_credentials", ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mismatch here as you're setting the `Content-Type` header to JSON, yet you're sending form-urlencoded. You need to use one or the other consistently.

If you want to explicitly use JSON, do this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token',
  contentType: 'application/json', // shorter than setting the headers directly, but does the same thing
  data: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: '***',
    client_secret: '***'
    resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
  }),
  success: data => {
    console.log(data.token)
  },
  error: (xhr, textStatus, error) => {
    console.log('rr', error)
  }
});
```

If you want to use a form-urlencoded string, do this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token',
  data: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=***&client_secret=***&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
  success: data => {
    console.log(data.token)
  },
  error: (xhr, textStatus, error) => {
    console.log('rr', error)
  }
});
```

Note in the above examples that the first argument to the `error` handler is not the request or response data as your example seems to expect. I've amended that part to accept the correct arguments.